# Don't have `r_emailaddress` or `r_liteprofile` scopes in linkedIn app API

Tags: linkedin-api

I just created an app in the LinkedIn developer portal however I am missing some scopes and I just can't seem to figure out how to get them. I have added the "Sign In with LinkedIn using OpenID Connect" and yet I do not have access to the `r_emailaddress` or `r_liteprofile` scopes.

I have created multiple apps over the last few days and still nothing. All of the LinkedIn documentation seems to assume that it will be there and I can't find out how to add it other than requesting the "Sign In with LinkedIn using OpenID Connect" product which I have done and has been approved.

I do have the `email` and `profile` scopes but many integrations such as Auth0 require `r_emailaddress` or `r_liteprofile`.

Any pointers or links on what to do will be very welcomed.

Comment: I am willing to use Profile API but the r_liteprofile permission required. The OPEN-ID Sign In does not provide this permission.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After digging around there is no solution. LinkedIn deprecated these scopes as of the 1st of August.

My specific example was Auth0. The issue there is they have not updated their system to reflect this change yet and I suspect many other services are the same.

For Auth0 there is an official documented workaround and issue to solve this;

https://community.auth0.com/t/the-linkedin-login-is-deprecated-updating-to-the-new-scopes-is-necessary/113696

Hope this helps anyone having the same issue.